Using AddHandler inside a Directory in Apache2
I am running apache2 on Debian 12 on DigitalOcean.
Following the mod_rewrite documentation, I am serving files out of two different directories. I am also using variables for my document root, because I have the same problem as this webmasters post.
The original problem: I want to allow cgi scripts to run, but only in the second directory, and I want to pass specific extensions to an interpreter.
I have set up a VirtualHost like the following:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org

  Define document_root /data/example.org/site
  DocumentRoot ${document_root}

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond "${document_root}%{REQUEST_URI}" -f [OR]
  RewriteCond "${document_root}%{REQUEST_URI}" -d
  RewriteRule "(.*)" "${document_root}$1" [L]

  <Directory ${document_root}>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Define script_dir /data/example.org/scripts
  RewriteCond "${script_dir}%{REQUEST_URI}" -f [OR]
  RewriteCond "${script_dir}%{REQUEST_URI}" -d
  RewriteRule "(.*)" "${script_dir}$1" [L]

  ScriptAlias /hello /data/example.org/scripts/hello.cgi
  <Directory ${script_dir}>
    Options +FollowSymlinks +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler text/xyz .xyz
    Action text/xyz /hello
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

If I navigate to example.org/abc.xyz, the file is downloaded instead of being passed to the hello.cgi script.
If I rewrite the virtual host so that the AddHandler directives are outside of the <Directory> block, then I am able to run my xyz scripts... but I'm able to run them from any directory. I want only the ones inside the /scripts directory to run. Is this possible?
